# can't convert string[] to string in vhdl

Tags: arrays, string, vhdl

i am writing a code in vhdl and bump into this error

```
 Assignment target incompatible with right side. Cannot convert 'dataArray' to 'STRING'
```

here is my code

```
 entity instructionTranslator is
    port(clk :in std_logic;
    instructionCode :in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    instructionType:out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) ;
    data :out string (1 to 1)--here is data
    );  
end instructionTranslator;
               .
               .
               .
architecture  Translator of instructionTranslator is    
    type dataArray is array (0 to 13)of string(1 to 1);

    process(clk) begin
      data<=dataArray(1);
```

how should chooses special index of array in vhdl.

Comment: `dataArray` is a type not an object of kind e.g. signal.

Comment: this has been asked so many times here... error due to using the type instead of the object created from the type. While it's the same in almost every programming language!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here. I made it into an [MCVE] for you. This one compiles.

You declared a type `dataArray`.
You didn't then go on to declare a signal (or variable or constant) of that type.

Assigning a member of a type (which is something abstract) to a real signal obviously won't work.

Assigning a member of a signal (etc) of that type, however, ...

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity instructionTranslator is
    port(clk :in std_logic;
    instructionCode :in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    instructionType:out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) ;
    data :out string (1 to 1)--here is data
    );  
end instructionTranslator;


architecture  Translator of instructionTranslator is    
    type dataArray is array (0 to 13)of string(1 to 1);
    signal da : dataArray;
begin

    process(clk) is
    begin
      data<=da(1);
    end process;
end Translator;
```